# Ng-repeat does not seem to create a separate Scope for each item when using array.push()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following Angular View:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
    <input ng-model="item.name"/>
</div>
```

In the controller, I call a service to get a Json representation of a new empty item so I can add it to the array with the following function:

```
$http.post("/NewItemJson").then(function (response) {
    $scope.newItem = response.data;
});

$scope.addItem = function() {
    $scope.items.push($scope.newItem);
};
```

But when I test the View, I see that all the new items added through the addItem() function are bound to the same scope. I can tell that because if I change one of the inputs, all the others change at the same time:

[image]

This is weird, because ng-repeat should create a different scope for each item. And it actually does, for all the items of the array not added with the addItem() function... but not in this case. What am I missing?

Comment: Where is your code that calls addItem? Is it possible you're just adding the same item?

Comment: I call the function from the View, with ng-click="addItem()". The items that I'm adding are empty objects... all the Id are empty Guids. Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't refresh `$scope.newItem` when you execute `addItem()`, so you're adding the same item over and over again. Try this:

```
$scope.addItem = function() {
    $scope.items.push(angular.copy($scope.newItem));
};
```

Comment: Correct. Thank you so much!